# Why is the if clause being skipped?

Tags: python, class, oop, python-3.x

```
# in file contactList.py
import contact
class ContactList:

    def __init__(self):

        self.added = True
        self.list = []

    def add(self, newContact):

        added = 1
        self.list.append(newContact)

    def __str__(self):

        if (self.added == True):
            returnedString = ""
            for contact in self.list:
                returnedString = returnedString + "\n" + str(contact)
    return returnedString

    def find(self, name):

        self.name = name
        for contact in self.list:
            if self.name == (str(contact))[0]: # I also tried if self.name in str(contact)
                return str(contact)
            else:
                return "Invalid input"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myFriends = ContactList()
    friend1 = contact.Contact("Mickey", "650-345-3333",    "Mickey@disneyland.com", "Disneyland, California")
    friend2 = contact.Contact("Minnie", "650-345-3344", "Minnie@disneyworld.com", "Disneyworld, Florida")
    friend3 = contact.Contact("Donald", "650-345-3333", "Donald@EuroDisney.com", "EuroDisney, France")
    myFriends.add(friend1)
    myFriends.add(friend2)  
    myFriends.add(friend3)
    print (myFriends)

    print (myFriends.find("Mickey"))
```

I'm wondering why the last call, `print (myFriends.find("Mickey"))`, is not be iterated by the shell; instead, it's skipped no matter what I put in the parameter. For example, when I enter "Mickey", "Minnie", or "Donald" in the parameter, I'm supposed to get the corresponding personal information about them, but the "if" clause under the `find()` function is never iterated. What's the problem here? Besides, since it was a snippet code to which I added `find()`, I'm not really sure what the purpose of the `self.added = True` in `__init__` and the `added = 1` in `add()`.

Below is the `contact()` imported to this file `contactList.py`

```
#in file contact.py
class Contact:

    """
    One object of class Contact represents one person's contact info.
    """
    def __init__(self, name, phone, email, streetAddress):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email
        self.streetAddress = streetAddress

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (self.name, self.phone,self.email,self.streetAddress)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    friend1 = Contact("Mickey", "650-345-3333", "Mickey@disneyland.com", "disneyland, CA")
    print (friend1)
```

Comment: What is `Contact`?

Comment: Does these even compile without error to a .pyc file? The reason I ask is that the `if` block isn't indented, or is this a typo. As you'll know, Python insists on indentation for the proper structure and running of code. So if that `if` cond is suposed to be part of the `find` method, it should be indented twice by the looks of things.

Comment: doing `(str(contact))[0]` gets the **first letter of the string** which is never equal to "Mickey" although it could be equal to `"M"`, either way your `else` statement will just stop the loop after the first element so it only checks the first thing added anyway.

Comment: @theruss `if` is under `for` and `for` is under `if`. There's no error reported regarding the indentation.

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen yea, I found that. Then I tried if...in statement, still cannot work.

Comment: Wouldn't you just want to do `if name == contact.name` ? or `if name == str(contact).split("\n")[0]` which applies your original logic of "get the first part of the string" but it would fall apart if the contact name happened to contain `"\n"` (and it is a lot harder to understand)

Comment: You said you copied and pasted this code from a sniped and just added the `find` method? I would rewrite the whole snippet from scratch. The code you copy-pasted is pretty clearly absolute garbage. I can tell even without understanding its purpose that it's poorly written and buggy. You're absolutely right to note that there are parts of the code that do absolutely nothing. There are also basic beginner python mistakes, like iterating through a list of strings with a `for` loop to concatenate. Seriously, you'd be better off writing it from scratch for yourself.

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen Exactly. But I have problem accessing the first element since `Contact()` imported from contact.py does not support indexing. And I cannot come up with a better way to match the parameter in `find()` to the first element in `self.list`.

Comment: I never suggested trying to index a `Contact` instance.... I recommended using the **`.name` attribute** but the original logic of "get the first part of the string" would need to be "get the string before the first `\n` character" which can be done with the `.split` method on strings, try reading my above comment again...

Comment: @machine yearning Hope my professor would never see your comment, haha. But it really is confusing.

Comment: No disrespect to your professor, he or she may be a great teacher, but my observation was just on the quality of the python code. Really looks like an absolute beginner wrote it, maybe he or she is a seasoned developer or computer scientist but is obviously not a python expert.

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen Thanks for your suggestion. I tried the `if name == contact.name ` statement you suggested, and it works only for the first element in `self.list`, that is, it only returns Mickey's info and does not work for Minnie and Donald. Could you help me take another look at it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as it is written will only check the first contact in the list. I'll just repeat what you have written here for clarity:

```
def find(self, name):
    self.name = name
    for contact in self.list:
        if self.name == (str(contact))[0]:
            return str(contact)
        else:
            return "Invalid input"
```

Now to be extra clear let's just keep the important parts:

```
if :# some condition is true
    return str(contact)
else: # some condition is false
    return "Invalid input"
```

As you can see in either case you get a return value. So you're not going to be finding your value if it's not the first one in your list, doesn't matter if the "some condition" referred to above is correct or buggy.

**Edit**: to be crystal clear, you need to put your failure condition (returning "invalid input" or whatever) *after* the `for` loop, not *inside of it*. This is left as an exercise to the reader.

Now as for the condition you're checking, based on the structure of the `Contact` class you posted I'd guess the right check would be:

```
if name == contact.name:
```

Nice and neat like python should be :)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

`(str(contact))[0]` gives the first character of the string representation of `contact`. So one character is never equal to a name with more than one character.

If `contact` has index access and the first index is actually the name, you should write:

```
def find(self, name):
    for contact in self.list:
        if name == contact[0]:
            return contact
    else:
        return "Invalid input"
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you put if statement in ().  you dont have to do it.
if self.added == True:
This way it will be enought.

Try this:
if self.name == str(contact[0])
Instead of this
if self.name == (str(contact))[0]

Comment: `if (self.added == True)` is completely syntactically valid, and works the same way as without `()`, same with `(str(contact))[0]` it works the exact same as `str(contact)[0]`.